# How to include click events and functionalities after on appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have radio buttons and a button, and they have their own functionalities, I want to append them to another div without losing their click events and functions,

I am working, with a woo-commerce word-press website, and I don't want to touch the behind JS code of the wp-plugin for the radio button and button because it so fragile I might break something and make things worst. is there a work around for this?

my code so far

```
<div id="foo">
   <button> // i don't have an access to the click function of this
   <radio button> // i don't have an access to the select function of this
</div>

<div id="bar">
</div>

$('bar').append('foo');
```

it appends the muck up, but you cant click on it.

Comment: Did you try with valid HTML ?

Comment: Also, [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/a9vhszqt/), appending an existing element just moves it, the events are intact.

Comment: what do you mean by valid html? the html is provided by wordpress I cannot modify it..

Comment: Does `<button><radio button>` look valid to you ?

Comment: I am just making my everything simple.. you get it right?

Comment: Please post your actual code. The developers who will try to help you will have a hard time doing so if you "simplify" things by writing invalid code. Where is the action of that button? Have you attempted to rebind the event to the button after moving it?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLKOPe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, is I used the clone and appendTo method in JQuery, first I clone the elements that I want to move to other container or div, then I set the display to none of the original, after that the all functionalities and events is working,

```
// the container
$('.new_con_here').append('<div class="new_con"> </div>');

// the element that I want to move
$('.elements').clone().appendTo('.new_con');

// set display none
$('.old_con > .elements').css('display', 'none');
```